# How to do "File in" in Pharo 6.1?

Tags: pharo, pharo-5, pharo-6

Wanting to migrate my small project from Pharo 5 to Pharo 6.1, and I happily found the **File Out** option when I right-clicked on my package and its classes. I saw it generates text files for those artifacts in my image directory (I'm running on Windows). So far, so good.

However, I looked everywhere for a menu to import these files back into Pharo 6.1 (right-clicked on the package list, etc.) to no avail. How does one do a **File In** (the opposite of **File Out**)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to file code in, is to just drag and drop the file onto the Pharo window. A dialog appears to ask you how you want to proceed.

Answer (score 6):

World menu > Tools > File Browser > (locate your changes file) + right-click > Changelist browser